# about Domain Age for main and sub-domains

Tags: seo

We are doing some SEO projects and I was just wondering wether the domain age for the main domain would always the same with its sub-domains?

I have seen both yes and no answers in other forums, just want to be sure.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Google doesn't see subdomains as being a separate domain or website](http://www.mattcutts.com/blog/subdomains-and-subdirectories/) so whatever applies the main domain will apply to the subdomain as well.

Comment: This does seem to be the mainstream answer and it does make sense.

Comment: Although sometimes Google does not index your subdomain, and there are also sayings that the subdomain will be treated as a new website, that is why it does not inherit page rank

Comment: PageRank is *per page* not *per website*. That's why no page inherits PageRank, You have to get it via incoming links. And anyone who says a subdomain is considered a new website is blatantly wrong as Matt Cutts has clearly debunked that myth (as shown in the link I provided).

Comment: True. Sorry for mixing up concepts here. There were sayings that google treat different pages for the same domain with better relavance that than its subdomain. just wondered whether that means that the domain age will not be recognized either